# Keras different model.evaluate() and model.predict() accuracy on the same data

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I need to be able to use predict on my model to test a benchmark but it doesn't work. When I use predict on the same validation data as my model uses whilst training, I only get an accuracy of .529. When using model.evaluate I get .85, it doesn't make sense and other threads talk about np.argmax or forgetting normalization but I've tried it all.

PS: I use transfer learning so it gets trained twice and some layers get frozen but that shouldn't influence this.

```
Model: "model_7"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_17 (InputLayer)        [(None, 150, 150, 3)]     0         
_________________________________________________________________
sequential_8 (Sequential)    (None, 150, 150, 3)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
normalization_7 (Normalizati (None, 150, 150, 3)       7         
_________________________________________________________________
xception (Functional)        (None, 5, 5, 2048)        20861480  
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d_7 ( (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_7 (Dropout)          (None, 2048)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 2049      
=================================================================
Total params: 20,863,536
Trainable params: 20,809,001
Non-trainable params: 54,535

model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(1e-5),  # Low learning rate
    loss=keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
    metrics=['accuracy', keras.metrics.BinaryAccuracy(),f1_m,precision_m, recall_m],
)
```

---

```
print(model.evaluate(x_test,y_test))

OUTPUT: 38/38 [==============================] - 2s 45ms/step - loss: 0.3570 - binary_accuracy: 0.8550 - f1_m: 0.8509 - precision_m: 0.8786 - recall_m: 0.8326
    [0.3569563925266266, 0.8550000190734863, 0.8509402871131897, 0.8786242604255676, 0.8326380848884583]
```

---

```
better = norm_layer(x_test)
# print(better[0])

y_pred = model.predict(better)
print(y_pred)
y_pred[y_pred <= 0.5] = 0
y_pred[y_pred > 0.5] = 1

print(y_pred)
print(sum(1 for x,y in zip(y_pred,y_test) if x == y) / len(y_pred))

OUTPUT: [[0.42335328]
     [0.3409149 ]
     [0.45328587]
     ...
     [0.38108858]
     [0.44630498]
     [0.76832736]]
    [[0.]
     [0.]
     [0.]
     ...
     [0.]
     [0.]
     [1.]]
    0.5291666666666667
```

---

Code normalization

```
# Pre-trained Xception weights requires that input be normalized
# from (0, 255) to a range (-1., +1.), the normalization layer
# does the following, outputs = (inputs - mean) / sqrt(var)
norm_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.Normalization()
mean = np.array([127.5] * 3)
var = mean ** 2
# Scale inputs to [-1, +1]
x = norm_layer(x)
norm_layer.set_weights([mean, var])
```

For full code the following link (the file Xception detection):
https://console.paperspace.com/tees0czt0/notebook/rj824evpaot143v?file=Xception%20detection.ipynb

Comment: What is the code for `norm_layer`?

Comment: I just added it

Comment: This is not really answerable unless you provide a self-contained reproducible example, there are too many missing details.

Comment: I also added a link for the full code.